# Programmatically constrain UILabels in Table Cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am programmatically creating my UITableViewCells with 3 labels and an image. 
Right now, all of my labels are overlapping and the cells have a fixed height.

The desired effect is to have a the image on the left at a fixed size and the labels start at 75 points from the left of the screen with one on each line.

Here is what I am going for:

`_____
|     |  Label 1
| img |  Label 2 with potentially multi-line text
|_____|  Label 3`

I'm not sure the best way to make the labels stack on top of each other and have the cells resize based on the three labels combine height.

```
self.title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[self.title setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[self.title setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:21/255 green:32/255 blue:48/255 alpha:1]];
[self.title setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:14.0f]];
[self.title setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.title setNumberOfLines:0];
[self.contentView addSubview:self.title];

self.description = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[self.description setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[self.description setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:21/255 green:32/255 blue:48/255 alpha:0.7]];
[self.description setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12.0f]];
[self.description setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.contentView addSubview:self.description];
[self.description setNumberOfLines:0];

self.user = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[self.user setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
[self.user setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:136/255 green:136/255 blue:136/255 alpha:1]];
[self.user setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10.0f]];
[self.user setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[self.user setNumberOfLines:0];
[self.contentView addSubview:self.user];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since you used `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO` I assume that you want to use VFL.

In you case I think the easiest way will be to set Autolayout in your XIB, But if you don't have one you can use VFL.

You can read about it here - [VFL](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/VisualFormatLanguage/VisualFormatLanguage.html)

Or here with code samples [VFL Tutorial](http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/01/31/visual-format-language-for-autolayout/)

Good luck

Comment: VFL, seems promising. First i've heard of it.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I have never understood how to write that. XIBs rules for autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

You set same frame coordinates for all three label.

```
self.title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

so you have to set three different frame for each label.

```
self.title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame1];
self.title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame2];
self.title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame3];
```

where frame1, frame2 and frame 3 have only distinct value of y coordinate.

```
frame2 = [75,"any constant value",70,10];
frame2 = [75,label1.frame.origin.y + 5,70,10];
frame3 = [75,label2.frame.origin.y + 5,70,10];
```

might this help you.